# django dynamic ajax form

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

i'm trying to write csv importer for my project that i can use for any model, it should be a wizard that first you upload the csv file, in the second step it generates a form based on the csv file for mapping csv field with database fields, on the first call to the form i should specify the model for the mapping, that can be a hidden input in the first form. on the other hand i want to use ajax for all the process, i don't know what to use exactly so it would be a complete reusable module and also with writing less java-script also how should i generate the second dynamic form. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Submit the first form through ajax. The request will contain (hidden) which form to use, so just render that form (based on a ModelForm). Make a template for each possible form(model) and return the rendered template accordingly.
The ajax call will remove the first form, on success and replace it with the response (which will be the second form).

Comment: well is there a better way? i mean i may have 50 models in my project and i don't want to have a separate form and template for each of them. i'm looking for a more dynamic way.

Comment: Then just use one template and make it generic for all of your forms.
In your view just inject the right Form into the template according to the POSTed data.

Comment: is there a good solution for dynamic form generation in django? or the best way is to generate the form dynamically by template system?

Comment: You can iterate easily over a forms field from within a template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#looping-over-the-form-s-fields